# How to solve ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I get this error when I try to import Keras into my project.

> How to solve ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`

I verified the versions I have installed (with pip) for everything and I have:

- Python 3.7.7
- Tensorflow 2.2.0
- keras 2.4.3

I have linked a picture of the full error. There is some stuff about Dll but I'm not sure if this is what creates the error.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 8):

Tensorflow requires Python 3.5–3.8 , pip and venv >= 19.0

in order to fix it:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip

pip3 install --upgrade pip

python3 -m pip install tensorflow
```

if you already had tensorflow installed substitute the last command this this:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

hope it helped.

Comment: During the upgrade, everything was saying "Requirement already satisfied" and after, keras is still not working and ask for tensorflow 2.2 or higher to be installed.

Comment: This told me "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow"

Answer (score 8):

ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`

Fix:

```
python -m pip install –upgrade pip
pip install keras==2.1.5
```

This worked for me.

If above step are not solving the error then check your libraries with specific version.

```
Python==3.6.4
Numpy==1.18.5
Pandas==1.1.4
scikit-learn==0.21.2
Tensorflow==1.13.1
keras==2.1.5
```

Hope this worked for you.

Answer (score -7):

Please update keras version.

```
python -m pip install –upgrade pip
```

Comment: you are here updating pip not keras